# Searching for a range [x,y] in a sorted vector in C++ [using lower_bound() and upper_bound() ]

Tags: c++, stl, lower-bound

I have an array of sorted vectors,

> **vector< int> b[1000009];**

Now I have to search the range between x and y inclusive in the row b[factor]. 

'factor', 'x' and 'y' are all integers.
 I have used the following approch :

```
        int lb,ub;
        if(b[factor][0]>=x){lb=0;}
        else
            {
                lb=upper_bound(b[factor].begin(),b[factor].end(),x)-b[factor].begin();
                while(b[factor][lb-1]>=x)lb--;
            }
        if(b[factor][sz2-1]<=y)
            {
                ub=sz2-1;
            }
        else {
                ub=lower_bound(b[factor].begin(),b[factor].end(),y)-b[factor].begin();
                while(b[factor][ub]>y)ub--;
            }
```

But this approach ain't giving correct answers all the time. And besides I would like to used some comparator functions to achieve the same. This is my first time with **lower_bound()** and **upper_bound()**. So please tell me how to implement the comparator function here.

Comment: Are your vectors sorted?

Comment: @vaughn- Yes they are already sorted, i forgot to mention.

Comment: Can you give an example of a case where you get the wrong answer?

Comment: I have a 146 lines program, in which i used this code segment, When I ran it, It gave me runtime error. When i replaced it by bruteforce checking through loop, it ran fine. So there must be some error over here?

Comment: what is the brute force equivalent that works?

Comment: simple loop from b[factor][0] to b[factor][b[factor].size()-1] and find positions for lb and ub.

Comment: What are the requirements for lb and ub?

Comment: lb is the position of the first element whose value >=x.

ub is the position of the last element whose value <=y.

Comment: so lb would be the position that lower_bound returns, and ub would be the position before what upper_bound returns.

Comment: Umm I don't understand the working of lower_bound and upper_bound properly.
I have to search the range [x,y] in  the vector b[factor] and lb stores the index of the begining of range and ub stores the index of the end of range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::lower_bound` returns the position of the first element whose value is greater than or equal to the argument.  `std::upper_bound` returns the position of the first element that is greater than the argument.  You can use these to iterate over the range of values between x and y like this:

```
  auto vb = b[factor].begin();
  auto ve = b[factor].end();
  auto lb = lower_bound(vb,ve,x);
  auto ub = upper_bound(vb,ve,y);
  for (auto i=lb; i!=ub; ++i) {
    // Do something with *i
  }
```

Let's take this example.  Say our vector contains these values:

> 1 3 4 7 9

And let's say x=3 and y=7.  `std::lower_bound(vb,ve,x)` will return the position of the first value that is greater than or equal to 3.  Since there is a value that is equal to 3, its position is what we will get for the lower bound.

`std::upper_bound(vb,be,y)` will return the position of the first value that is greater than 7.  That would be the position of 9 in this case.

So our loop is going from the position of 3 up to, but not including, the position of 9, which is exactly the range of values that we want.

Now what if x=5 and y=6.  There would be no values in that range.  What would it do?

The first value that is greater than or equal to 5 is 7.  The first value that is greater than 6 is also 7.  So `lb` and `ub` would be the same position!  Our loop would terminate immediately, which is exactly what we want since there are no elements in our range.

Comment: The descriptions of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` seem a little confusing at first, especially since they're so similar. But once you see how they're supposed to be used it really is simple.

Comment: won't we need any comparator function? The functions here are <= and >= not > and < ??

Comment: @dhruv: `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` are doing the comparison for you.

Comment: and can you tell me what lb and ub will have if there are no elements b/w x and y in our vector?

Comment: @dhruv: In that case, lb and ub will be the same position, and the loop will stop immediately.

Comment: Cool. Now I understand it, Thank You.